# Construct Dataframe from Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    "Title": "Import/Export",
    "Values": [{
            "Region": "East",
            "Currency": "USD",
            "Amount": "32"
        },
        {
            "Region": "West",
            "Currency": "USD",
            "Amount": "325"
        }
    ],
    "Code": "21"
}
```

I want the resulting dataframe to look like this:

```
Title             Region     Currency   Amount   Code
Import/Export     East       USD        32       21
Import/Export     West       USD        325      21
```

How do I go about doing this? I've tried a lot of things like pandas convert to a dataframe and jons_normalize, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Your dictionary seems to have some problems. Try editing to question, please.

Comment: you haven't provided valid inputs. Did you mean to put that opening quote after `'Values':`?

Comment: Did you tend to define a list for the `Values` column? Because it is started with a single quotation mark and ended with a "]".

Answer (score 0):

It seems your input has a problem. But I thought you might have wanted to define it such as what follows:

```
'Title': 'Import/Export',
'Values': [{"Region":"East","Currency":"USD","Amount":"32"}, {"Region":"West", "Currency":"USD", "Amount":"325"}],
"Code":"21"
```

If so, you can use code below:

```
dictionary = {'Title': 'Import/Export','Values': [{"Region":"East","Currency":"USD","Amount":"32"}, {"Region":"West", "Currency":"USD", "Amount":"325"}],"Code":"21"}
df = pd.DataFrame(dicti)
newColumns = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  values = row["Values"]
  for key, value in values.items():
    if key not in newColumns:
      newColumns[key] = []
    newColumns[key].append(value)
for columnName, columnValue in newColumns.items():
  df[columnName] = columnValue
df = df.drop(columns=["Values"])
df
```

##### Output

|  | Title | Code | Region | Currency | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Import/Export | 21 | East | USD | 32 |
| 1 | Import/Export | 21 | West | USD | 325 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_normalize` like this way.

```py
# data is the param for the dictionary.
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['Values'], meta=['Title', 'Code'])
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: `TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Could you print your dictionary exactly?  it suggest that you have strings for where it should be a list, perhaps `Values'.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data["Values"]).assign(
    **{k: v for k, v in data.items() if k != "Values"}
)
```

Would suffice, or even just:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data["Values"]).assign(Title=data["Title"], Code=data["Code"])
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since data['values'] is an array right? It'll give: `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: @user2896120 no. For starters, that is a `list`, but in any case, the `pd.DataFrame` constructor happily accepts a list of dictionaries.

Comment: You're right, my full dataframe seems like there's something wrong with it